# Shell Scripting question | ${-#*i} meaning in profile

Tags: shell

I was looking into a shell file and I have found this part:

```
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
if [ -r "$i" ]; then
    if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then
        . "$i"
    else
        . "$i" >/dev/null 2>&1
    fi
fi 
done
```

and I was wondering what does `${-#*i}` mean in this context ?

Comment: Please read the [tag:shell] description and then add the actual shell's tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a POSIX shell, `-` is a special shell variable. From the man page:

> ```
>  - (Hyphen.)  Expands to the current option flags (the single-letter option
>               names concatenated into a string) as specified on invocation,
>               by the set builtin command, or implicitly by the shell.
> ```

The `#` is used to return a variable's value with part of it removed:

> ```
>  ${parameter#word}     Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern.  The word is expanded
>                        to produce a pattern.  The parameter expansion then
>                        results in parameter, with the smallest portion of the
>                        prefix matched by the pattern deleted.
> ```